# Derivative of inverse of a matrix expression?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization

How to find the following derivative?

$\frac{d}{du} (u^TAu)^{-1} $

I know how to find the derivative without the inverse, that's just 2Au. But what about that?

Comment: There is actually a trace operator at the outside, but hey, the thing is scalar, so what's the point of it? I removed it.

Comment: It sounds easier than I think.

Comment: The inner derivative is not $2Au$ if $A$ is not symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Find the differential of the scalar, then of its reciprocal, and finally the gradient.
$$\eqalign{
 \alpha &= u^TAu \cr
d\alpha &= (du^TAu + u^TA\,du) = du^T(A+A^T)u \cr
d\alpha^{-1} &= -\frac{d\alpha}{\alpha^2} = du^T\,\bigg(\frac{(A+A^T)u}{-\alpha^2}\bigg) \cr
\frac{\partial \alpha^{-1}}{\partial u} &= \frac{(A+A^T)u}{-\alpha^2} \cr
}$$